# JSON from c# asmx returns escaped string format not JSON object

Tags: c#, ajax, json, web-services, entity-framework

My JSON is returning as an escaped string, I want the object without backslashes and outer quotes. I'm sure I'm missing a cast or something simple but I'll put the full code here to avoid misinterpretation.

I'm trying to get some data into a Infragistics Ignite UI grid via ajax/JSON/asmx web service. I've got data coming back, but it's not in the correct format. I'm not sure if the issue is in my ajax js or c# method return type (string), or the JSON serialisation?

Here's how I get call the web service using jquery ajax call:

```
    var jqxhr = $.ajax(
                {
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "/WebMethods/AssetWebService.asmx/GetAssets",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: success,
                    error: function (xhr, msg) { alert(msg + '\n' + xhr.responseText); }
                });

    function success(msg) {
        var entityColumns = getColumns();
        var entityData = msg.d;
        gridSetup(entityData, entityColumns);
    }

    function gridSetup(entityData, entityColumns) {
        $("#assetGrid").igGrid(
            {
                autoGenerateColumns: false,
                autoGenerateLayouts: false,
                dataSource: entityData,
                columns: entityColumns
            }
       );
    }
```

Webservice c# code getting objects from entity framework:

```
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class AssetWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public string GetAssets()
        {
            List<Asset> Assets  = new List<Asset>();

        using (var db = new CognyxMES())
        {
            Assets = db.Assets.ToList();
        }

        var results = from a
                          in Assets
                          select new
                          {
                              Id = a.Id,
                              Name = a.Name,
                              AssetTypeId = a.AssetTypeId
                          };
        return results;            
        }
    }
```

The JSON that I am getting returned looks like this when I debug in VS2013 (which causes my grid to not display any data):

```
"[{\"Id\":3,\"Name\":\"My Asset\",\"AssetTypeId\":1}]"
```

I want to it to look like this as my grid works when I hard code this in:

```
[{ "Id": 3, "Name": "My Asset", "AssetTypeId": 1 }]
```

I am new to JSON with c# so I know I could use string replace or similar to hack it into place but I'm after a more elegant fix and explanation of what I'm missing. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are returning `IS` a string and not `JSON`.  That is your problem.

Your method should look like so.  ASP.NET handles the rest for you.

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public IEnumerable<object> GetAssets()
    {
        using (var db = new assetEntities())
        {
            var results = from a
                          in db.Assets
                          select new
                          {
                              Id = a.Id,
                              Name = a.Name,
                              AssetTypeId = a.AssetTypeId
                          };
            return results;
        }
    }
```

`Based on your jQuery request you have specified that you want JSON  and your`ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Jsonreturned` forces this... so your webservice will serialize the response to JSON for you.  Easy-peasy. No manual serializing needed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and sample code, I understand now and have it working. Once I updated the return type I received a 'dbcontext has been disposed' error so I have updated my sample to reflect the modified GetAssets() method. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

```
ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json
```

You just told ASP.Net to convert your response to JSON.
Therefore, you should return a raw object, not a JSON string.

By returning a string, you're telling ASP.Net to serialize *that string* to JSON, which is not what you want.